# how to update unique default option in one sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mybatis

i have table like this

```
-----------------------
id | name | is_default|
------------------------
1  | a    |  1        |
2  | a    |  0        |
3  | a    |  0        |
4  | a    |  0        |
-----------------------
```

now i want to change line 2(id =2) is_default to 1,and origin line(id =1) id_default to 0 at the same time,like the choose default option in list in UI.
1.can i do this in one sql statement?
2.if it is possible,how to write the sql statement or how to write in mybatis mapper.xml?

Springboot with mybatis ,sql statement write in mapper.xml

```
@Data
pulbic class Option{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private Boolean isDefault;
}
```

how to write the mybatis or mysql statement?

Answer (score 4):

You may use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET is_default = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

Or, if you intended to just toggle the default values for `id` 1 and 2, then try:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET is_default = CASE WHEN is_default = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is fine.  If the values are only 0/1, you can simplify it to:

```
UPDATE t
    SET is_default = 1 - is_default
    WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```